# How to get data from simple text line by line

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oop, split

I am trying to extract data from text. It is larger text. For better understanding. I have simple class Test with one atribute result, which is enum.

```
class Test{

 private Result result;
 
 public Test(string text){
  this.Result = FindProblem(text);
 }
......

public enum Result
    {
        SUCCESS = 1,
        FAIL = 2,
        NONE = 3

    }


 }
```

Then I have text:

> Today at 01:05: (NAME) Failed Backup - The operation encountered an error. (NAME)
> Failed when backing up:
> A file was not found (NAME)
> DISK_OPEN_ERROR
>
> Today at 01:04: (NAME) Successful Backup - Backed 42,73 MB (compressed to 7,32 MB).(Duration: 1 minute)
>
> Today at 00:59: (NAME) Successful Backup - Backed 3,41 GB (compressed to 379,17 MB).(Duration: 4 minutes)

And I want each row to return a Test object with results like: **result: Failed**
or **result: Succesful**.

Method for returning all objects from text

```
public Result FindResult(string text)
        {
            var splitText = text.Split("\n").ToList();
            Result r = Result.NONE;
            foreach (var item in splitText)
            {
                if (item.Contains("Failed"))
                {
                    r = Result.FAIL;
                }
                else
                {
                    r = Result.SUCCESS;
                }
            }
            return r;
        }
```

But it returns only result SUCCESS.
Expected output

```
  result:FAIL
  result:SUCCESS
  result:SUCCESS
```

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the value of `r` on each iteration...keeping only the value of the last iteration?

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is good guess

Comment: so how could I rewrite `r` on each iteration? I take it the return on the last line is wrong? Or does return only return the value it gets on the first line?

Comment: Currently you pass a single string, split it on a newline and that will give you a list of strings. What do you want this function to return? Right now you are returning a single result, which is `r` but the list has multiple items. If there can be more items in the list that can contain `Failed` you can return another data structure that contains 1 or more strings that have `Failed`

Comment: I have edited my example little bit. In the text are 3 problems, so I would like to create 3 `objects`, in this case `Test`. I have also added expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do is split on at least 2 newlines, and then map the items in the list using Select and check if it contains "Failed"

If it does, return `Result.FAIL`, else return `Result.SUCCESS` so the return type of the function is `List<Result>`

```
class Test
{
    private Result result;
    public enum Result
    {
        SUCCESS = 1,
        FAIL = 2,
        NONE = 3    
    }

    public List<Result> FindResult(string text)
    {
         return Regex
        .Split(text, @"\r?\n\s*\r?\n")
        .Select(s => s.Contains("Failed") ? Result.FAIL : Result.SUCCESS)
        .ToList();            
    }
}
```

And then you can loop the items in the returned list

```
Test test = new Test();
var results = test.FindResult(input);
foreach(var r in results) {
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Output

```
FAIL
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/erM0bH).

Comment: Thats look good, But is it possible to do it this inside the class? Without the part with `result `and `foreach` in Main? Like in my example

Comment: @Petr The function `FindResult` returns `List<Result>` so that already returns what you want. The `foreach` part is just an example to loop and print what is contained within in the returned list. Do you want the function `FindResult` to return a string with the output FAIL and SUCCESS?

Comment: I was wondering if I would  have another class, let's say `AnotherTest`, and this class would have only one property, the `Test` class. And I would like that with each creation of the class `AnotherTest`, a new class `Test` would be created, which would have just the values listed from your example from `foreach`

Comment: @Petr See this example https://dotnetfiddle.net/FlycX9

Comment: I had something like this on my mind https://dotnetfiddle.net/HDUqLw

Comment: @Petr You can implement it any way you like :-) I think that in your example you do not really use `this.result = Result.NONE;` as you will never set that value. There is just `FindResult` that returns a list of Results that you will later on turn into a string representation.

Comment: That way, my initial thought was that I would return a new `object` every time I read a line.
For example.
Line 1: Today at 01:05: (NAME) Failed Backup - The operation encountered an error. (NAME)
Failed when backing up: A file was not found (NAME)
DISK_OPEN_ERROR
and the method would return (and probably store the object somewhere in some DB) a new `Test` object with the `Fail`
and so on until there was something to select

Comment: @Petr What you can do then is split the string on newlines which gives you a list. Then map that list to a list of objects (of your type) that AND have the Result type AND the string that was checked for "Failed". That way you have a list of objects that know the Result per string.

Comment: So I suppose I can take your example

Comment: @Petr Take a look at this example with an object that has both values https://dotnetfiddle.net/oLU143